# How to show webpage having giphy iframe in android webview?

Tags: android, html, android-layout, iframe, webview

I am showing a webpage which has some gif iframe inside. whole page is loaded but instead of showing gif, its only showing "via Giphy".
when i clicked on it opens the gif on browser. 
I tried android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
but not succeed.
Please suggest.
[image]

Comment: Where do you get those data?

Comment: I found this page: http://www.allaboutwomen.in/5-secret-ways-make-friday-super-amazing/

Comment: I am getting url in shouldOverrideUrlLoading method. i.e. file://giphy.com/embed/83e0YbTT50 but its not showing.

Comment: Please share your code, I tried with a simple WebView and it's working

Answer (score 0):

In order to animate the gif from Giphy, Javascript must be enabled.

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Else it will show a static image.
Gif doesn't show immediately, but it shows a blank rectangle while it's loading.